# Selecting all rows in Joomla 3.x doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a table with 300 rows. I wrote a SQL query in a Joomla 3 component to select all rows, but when I executed that query I got only a part of my table. Can someone help me, how can I get all rows, please. This is my query:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__huge_it_catalog_params');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Feel free to add the database you are actually using as a tag.

Comment: my database name is "kx8wp_huge_it_catalog_params"

Comment: Sorry, my table name is kx8wp_huge_it_catalog_params. And I use  mysql MyISAM type

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__huge_it_catalog_params');
$value = $app->input->get('limit', $app->get('list_limit', 0), 'uint');
$this->setState('list.limit', $value);
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: $query->select('*');

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it that way:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')->from('#__huge_it_catalog_params');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code its working fine for me.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__huge_it_catalog_params";
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```